# How do I fire up an event on any keyboard, mouse or gamepad state change?

Tags: c#, events, input, xna

Is there a way to immediately react to any change in the states of mouse, keyboard and gamepad(s) in a C# application?

I believe XNA is just like any other C# app, so it might not be any different, but just in case, I want to improve my XNA game input by immediately firing up corresponding events.

Default XNA doesn't have an event handler (at least I've never seen it being mentioned). Nuclex.Input doesn't detect some keys (like Alt, F10 or Pause, which is unacceptable).

Answer (score 0):

Normally you store the state of the input on the previous frame, and then test whether then input has changed between frames. For example, your `Update` method might look like:

```
KeyboardState ks = Keyboard.GetState();

if(ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && lastKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space))
{
    DoAThing();
}

lastKeyboardState = ks;
```

(Wrote that code entirely from memory, so it might not be quite right. But it should illustrate the concept.)

This will give you key events with no more than `1 / yourFPS` delay. At 60FPS this is about 16ms. This is usually acceptable for gameplay purposes. If you especially want an `event` - you could simply fire one where I have put `DoAThing`, above.

---

For typing **text** you generally want the character events from Windows (which a library like `Nuclex.Input` can give you). This isn't so much so you get better latency, but so you can get keyboard events in an **ordered** and **reliable** way (for example: this way you never get two key coming down on a single frame resulting in an ambiguous order).

More importantly, it's so you can get the events after Windows has had a chance to apply input processing. For example, this gives you difference between typing an `a` and an `A`. Or someone entering a character with alt+numpad, or applying a diacritic. The downside is that you miss out on various non-text keys like, as you mention, `Alt`, `F10`, `Pause`, etc.

---

Finally, a quick read over `Nuclex.Input` reveals that it at least *should* provide the keys that you want - specifically `IKeyboard.KeyPress` and `.KeyRelease`. If it's not working, it could be a bug in `Nuclex`. Or something on your system is interfering with window messages.

One possible work-around might be to accept the latency on these missing keys by polling for them as well. The code to use polling as a seamless fall-back is probably fairly simple.

Comment: The latency from one `Update` to the next comes from missing some input on one update (which has already gone off and started processing and drawing that frame) and having to wait until the next one. This gives you a latency between input and processing between 0 and 16ms at 60FPS. (Note that `Keyboard.GetState` and `Mouse.GetState` get values immediately from Windows and do not buffer!) Do you really need lower latency? Only music-grade audio requires it - think MIDI keyboards, etc (humans are far more latency-sensitive to sound that visuals).

Comment: @user1306322 (Also I just added an update to my answer about `Nuclex.Input`)

Comment: I guess I'll have to unlock the game's update rate and update input as fast as possible without events.